# How can players catch the same discs that are used to destroy-cut other players and/or break the ground?

Tags: tron-legacy

In Tron Legacy, they play a game where you have to kill another program (or user) by throwing a disc. They also can throw it to destroy segments of the floor. But when the disk returns, they can catch it without cutting themselves. How do they do this? Do the disks have a grippable area? Is it the gloves? (which look to be of the same material of the rest of the suit by the way) Are they programmed not to hurt the user? Is it just a plothole?

How can players catch the same discs that are used to destroy-cut other players and/or break the ground?

Comment: Very carefully indeed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the official novelisation for Tron, the razor edge of the identity disc is an extension of the player's *aura*. When the disk hits the opponent, their aura is damaged and this typically leads to them derezzing. It stands to reason that a disc wouldn't damage your own aura, if caught correctly.

> There was a violent release of energy, smashing the Blue down onto the Game Grid. The red aura of the disk triumphed over the Blue’s aura, enveloping the prone Warrior. He de-resolved, fading rapidly from sight, becoming a swirl of static.
>
> <sub><sup>[Tron: Novelisation](https://tron.fandom.com/wiki/TRON_(novelization))</sup></sub>

You may also want to note that discs thrown by battling allies can also be caught without injury (as seen in Tron: Upsrising where Beck and Cutler inadvertently catch each others discs) so the discs appear to be intelligent enough to recognise what's an enemy and what isn't.

Comment: A fair answer.  One does wonder if they might work on dodgeball principles though...  :-) Catch it and you're fine, anything else and you're out.  (Dead.)